# Android - I set a custom background for a listView, and the highlight has gone

Tags: android, listview, background

Ok, now this is my SimpleAdapter's getView function:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      view.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.color1);

      return view;
    }
}
```

And this is my color1.xml file, in res/drawable-lpi folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#FFFF00FF"/> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="#FF0000FF"/> <!-- selected -->

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#FF0000FF"/> <!-- focused -->  

    <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Why i still get this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that all background settings functions of a View, actually change its background-drawable.

- The [setBackgroundColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) actually
  creates a ColorDrawable.
- The [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) actually loads a drawable resource
- The [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), obviously, uses a drawable.

When you call setBackgroundColor with your highlight.xml, you actually try to create a ColorDrawable with the value of the generated ID of R.drawable.highlight.

You actually need to call the setBackgroundResource method, which is equivalent to the "android:background" XML tag.

Your highlight.xml is actually a state-list, which is an instance of [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). 
If you wanted to only change the colors, you could use a [color-state-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are using `setBackgroundColor()` which takes an integer color value... you need to use `setBackgroundResource()`.